# Is it possible to create a process which will always clean up after itself?

Tags: c#, process

I'd like to create a new process which will clean up after itself, even if the calling process has terminated. I've mocked up an example below, using notepad to display a temporary file, which I'd like to be deleted after notepad is closed.

In the code below, this works as expected if I uncomment the WaitForExit() line or alternatively go into a infinite loop to mimic the calling program running. The main problem is when the calling program finishes, since the event is no longer handled.

I'd appreciate any suggestions on how to handle this case.

Regards,

Chris

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string filename = @"c:\temp\example.txt";
        if (!File.Exists(filename))
            File.WriteAllText(filename, "abc");

        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("notepad", filename);

        Process cmdProcess = new Process();

        Process p = new Process();
        psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
        p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        p.StartInfo = psi;
        p.Exited += (sender, e) => { File.Delete(filename); };

        p.Start();
        //p.WaitForExit();
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand **why** did you comment the last line. I know it blocks the caller thread (ie. your program) but that might be exactly what **you want**

Comment: I'd like the caller thread (my program) to carry on it's life afterwards, totally independent of sub-process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sneaky way would to write a batch file which does approx this:

```
notepad c:\temp\example.txt
del c:\temp\example.txt
```

and then have your process execute the batch instead.

Working sample (save as c:\test.bat):

```
echo FOO > c:\test.txt
notepad c:\test.txt
del c:\test.txt
del c:\test.bat
```

Comment: Thanks liho1eye - that's the current solution, but it lacks a certain elegance imho :)

Comment: You can create third "monitor" process that does essentially the same thing. Then your solution would be purely C#, but a bit more code and complexity of extra project/executable. The bottom line is that somebody has to do it (perform cleanup action) and notepad cannot do it, since you have no control over it.

Comment: I'm still a little disappointed with the hackyness of this answer, but appreciate it's probably the best that can be done given the circumstances. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

If the calling process has exited it can no longer do anything; it doesn't exist.

One option would be to create another thread that is **not** a background thread (set [`IsBackground`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground.aspx) to false)  and call WaitForExit on that thread; that will keep the process alive during normal exit from Main. However, this cannot do anything if the process terminates abnormally (task manager *kill*, or simply pulling out the power).

Comment: Thanks Marc - interesting suggestion that I'll investigate. As for abnormal termination, that's something I can live with.

Comment: Problem with this is that the calling program can't then finish until the process it created finishes. Is there a way for the new process to do this cleanup on it's own accord?